# Add image on title area of a table with gt package in R

Tags: r, gt

This is my table:

```
library(gt)
gt(mtcars)
```

All I want is to include a png image ([image]) file on the top left or top right of this table with a local png file. On the title area.

All I manage to do was this.

```
 gt(mtcars) %>% tab_header(title = md("&#x26BD;**2014 - 2019 Salary and Playoff Appearances**&#x26BD;"))
```

But I have no idea how can I include a png image **on title area**

Any help?

Comment: Follow this link and you will have the solution for how to add picture to the title with gt package: https://community.rstudio.com/t/insert-image-in-title-in-gt-table/96820

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
gt(mtcars) %>% tab_header(title = md("<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyMtM.png' style='height:30px;'> **2014 - 2019 Salary and Playoff Appearances**&#x26BD;"))
```

Comment: Bloxx many thanks for your time! Its look like I need to upload my file?

Comment: You can also put the path to your local file in `src` argument.

Answer (score 0):

With a *local file*, it could be done like this:

```
library(gt)

mtcars |> 
  gt() |> 
  tab_header(title = html("My heading", local_image("UyMtM.png")))
```

[image]